# Reading Binary file in C

Tags: c, file-io, binaryfiles

I am having following issue with reading binary file in C.

I have read the first 8 bytes of a binary file. Now I need to start reading from the 9th byte. Following is the code:

```
fseek(inputFile, 2*sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
```

However, when I print the contents of the array where I store the retrieved values, it still shows me the first 8 bytes which is not what I need.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`fseek` just moves the position pointer of the file stream; once you've moved the position pointer, you need to call `fread` to actually read bytes from the file.

However, if you've already read the first eight bytes from the file using `fread`, the position pointer is left pointing to the ninth byte (assuming no errors happen and the file is at least nine bytes long, of course).  When you call `fread`, it advances the position pointer by the number of bytes that are read.  You don't have to call `fseek` to move it.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Also, can you tell me how I can skip a specific number of bytes? Currently, I am only reading the number of bytes I want to skip in a byte array to move the cursor. Am wondering if there is any library that does perform the same function.

Comment: @darkie15: Then you want to use `SEEK_CUR`, not `SEEK_SET`, which tells `fseek` to use the offset relative to the current position, instead of the start of the file.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming:

```
FILE* file = fopen(FILENAME, "rb");
char buf[8];
```

You can read the first 8 bytes and then the next 8 bytes:

```
/* Read first 8 bytes */
fread(buf, 1, 8, file); 
/* Read next 8 bytes */
fread(buf, 1, 8, file);
```

Or skip the first 8 bytes with `fseek` and read the next 8 bytes (8 .. 15 inclusive, if counting first byte in file as 0):

```
/* Skip first 8 bytes */
fseek(file, 8, SEEK_SET);
/* Read next 8 bytes */
fread(buf, 1, 8, file);
```

The key to understand this is that the C library functions keep the *current position* in the file for you automatically. `fread` moves it when it performs the reading operation, so the next `fread` will start right after the previous has finished. `fseek` just moves it without reading.

---

P.S.: My code here reads *bytes* as your question asked. (Size 1 supplied as the second argument to `fread`)

Comment: Note: if you wish to `read 8, skip 8, read 8` use SEEK_CUR, like so: `fread(buf, 1, 8, file);fseek(file, 8, SEEK_CUR);fread(buf, 1, 8, file);`